# Javascript Accessing Multidimensional Array Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, key

I have a javascript array that looks like this:

```
'40x27'  => array(  
    '1' => 0  
    '1.5' => 2  
    '2' = 1  
)  
'36x24' => array(   
    '1' => 1  
    '1.5' => 1  
    '2' = 2
)
```

etc.

I want to print out the values of the inner array like this:

```
i = 0;
for (i in outerArray){
    var k = 0;
    for (k in innerArray){
        alert(innerArray[k]);
    }//for
}//for
```

The issue I am having is that the `k` variable has the value of `outerArray[i]` instead of the key of the `innerArray` like so:

```
i=0;k="40x27";  
i=0;k="36x24";  
i=1;k="40x27";  
i=1;k="36x24";
```

**Edit**:  sorry I forgot to include some code.

var outerArrays=new Array("40x27","36x24");
var innerArray=new Array("1","1.5","2");

Comment: You appear to missing some code here.  Where/how are outerArray and innerArray assigned?

Comment: I added the missing code.  it is declared at the top of the document.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting `innerArray` to anything. Try this:

```
for (var i in outerArray) {
    var innerArray = outerArray[i];
    for (var k in innerArray) {
        alert(innerArray[k]);
    }
}
```

BTW, these are not typically called arrays in Javascript like they are in PHP. Arrays in Javascript are sequences, while objects are maps from strings to arbitrary types like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the pointers, once i took a look at how I created the arrays I realized that i had a dumb syntax error:

```
for (i in outerArray){   
    var k = 0;  
    for(k in **innerArray[outerArray[i]]**){  
        alert(innerArray[k]);  
    } //for
} //for
```

thanks!  you guys rock.